Suggestion for catching a flight with short layover in Paris
I am an Indian citizen (Indian Passport) who is travelling Business class from Detroit, US to Mumbai, India with an stopover in Paris, France.
My flight is AF377 9:00 pm Detroit to 9:50 am (+1) Paris and then AF218 10:55 am Paris to 00:05 am Mumbai (+1).
It’s a very short layover, moreover I will be traveling with my wife who is an Indian citizen and an infant who is an American citizen. My wife and I both have a Canadian visa stamped on passport; we also have Advance Parole card from US (instead of visa; as our Green card is in progress)
Tickets have been booked through Priceline and have the same PNR.
Please help provide some suggestion to ensure I catch the flight.

Are both flights at CDG?

yes both from CDG

In a comment to your other question, you say that it's on a single ticket (if it's the same trip, in that post you state the layover to be 1h 10min), in that case it's the airline's responsibility to get you to Mumbai, so they'll do what they can to allow you to catch the flight.

Can you change the second leg to a later flight? Although if this is a genuine connecting ticket AF would be responsible for getting you to your destination. If I were you I’d check the airline website to see if AF actually offers this connection. One other consideration is that if the inbound flight is late, you and your family might well make the connection with assistance from the airline, but your luggage might not. Personally I wouldn’t have booked such a tight connection.

Do you plan to have a gate-checked stroller or anything like that? That may complicate things a bit but I have no experience with that.

Planning to avoid gate checking the stroller, instead will check that in at counter to avoid any delay

Anecdotally, I once did not make it with similar times. It was crowded all over, had to take a bus to the gate, for whatever reason they initially couldn't issue my second boarding pass, the first leg was 10ish minutes late.. it adds up.

Since both your flights are on the same PNR:

You do not have to go through passport control in CDG
You don’t have to deal with checked luggage or check-in formalities in CDG
You will probably already have your boarding passes for the next flight. If not, there are kiosks to retrieve them (or you can/should use the mobile app).
You will most probably have to go through security, but your business class ticket gives you access to the priority lane (“Accès N°1 / Sky Priority”).

So it’s really just a matter of:

Deplaning
Going to the right concourse. This may involve using the automated people mover
Going through security
Going to your gate

Even in the worst case (gate K58 to gate M50) this should be doable without a problem, and that should be the case over 90% of the time. There can be quite a bit of a walk, but there are many travelators and escalators.
Note that your first flight most often arrives early, but delays do happen. Out of the 12 last flights, AF377 was on time or early 9 times, had a very small delay of 4 and 8 minutes on two occasions, and was nearly 2 hours late once.
On some flights there are passport checks right at the gate when deplaning to isolate transit passengers deemed at risk of trying to enter France, but I believe this to be very unlikely for a flight arriving from the US.
If the flight is slightly late (and possibly even if not) you will probably have AF personnel to pick you up at the arrival gate and escort you to the destination gate so you don’t get lost on the way. They can hold the second flight a little bit if necessary. Personnel at the gate will know you are a connecting passenger, when your flight arrived, and whether you have reached security.
If your incoming flight is so late that you cannot make the connection, then they will rebook you on the next available flight.
The difficulty here is that this is the only AF direct flight to Mumbai of the day, and that there is not even a flight every day, so rebooking will be a tad complex. Either they put you on the next day’s flight (if there is one and there are availabilities) and pay for hotel and meals until then (there’s a hotel airside in CDG 2E Gates L — but you won’t be able to leave the airport), or they reroute you via other cities, partners, or airlines. Note that it is their obligation to try to find you a flight the same day even if it means rebooking you on a different airline (e.g. the Vistara flight in the evening), though they will only do that if they cannot reroute you the same day via their own flights or partners.
It would probably be a good idea to look at the possible alternative routes before you depart, so you are ready to make an informed choice if the case arises.
If your first flight is delayed at the origin, it may be worth it to ask to be rerouted right there. Again, looking at alternative options in advance is helpful. Remember to have multiple options (including pure AF, pure Skyteam, and others), as availability may be limited. And look at the final arrival time: sometimes they can reroute you on a first flight leaving shortly, only to have a very long layover somewhere else.
Of course, make sure you know which alternate routings are compatible with your passport/visa situation. For instance, they cannot reroute you via Amsterdam: this would require a Schengen visa.
In all cases (even if your first flight is in time, sadly), there’s also the risk your luggage may not make the connection and be delayed. Out an AirTag or equivalent in each piece of luggage before you leave. At least you will know where it is.
Note also that if you arrive late and there are no “extraordinary circumstances” then you may be eligible for compensation.
In terms of suggestions:

Look at the terminal maps of CDG and understand your itinerary in the various cases. You may arrive at either of K, L or M gates and depart from either of the three.
If you stay within the same concourse, you just go towards the centre of the concourse, go through security, and then to your gate.
If you have to change concourse, go to the centre of the concourse, take the people mover to the other concourse. Go through security and on to your gate.
Always follow “connection” signs to the relevant gates. Do not go to passport control, baggage claim, exit, or to any other terminal.

Have the AF app in your phone, be logged in, with your booking showing and notifications enabled. You will be able to look up delays, gates, and get notifications.

I would usually recommend to get seats towards the front of the plane on the first flight, but you are already in business class, so you should be among the first to leave the plane.

If your flight is due to arrive slightly late, talk to cabin crew. They will be in touch with operations and know what to do.

Get your gate number before deplaning. Note that if the gate number is on the boarding pass (unlikely IMHO) it may have changed since then.

Look up in advance the alternative flights in case of delays either at the origin or in CDG.

While I don’t think the (relatively) short connection is an issue by itself (if there are no significant delays you will make it, and that over 90% of the time), combined with limited alternatives for re-routing, it may make sense to try to rebook on a different itinerary, but long-haul flights like these are nearly always infrequent so there aren’t necessarily too many options with a layover time which is not too short and not too long either.

If you want really be on the safe side, a stopover (staying overnight) in Paris could be a good idea, but in your case you would need Schengen visas.


Good luck!

Thanks so so much for detailed answer. Its a relief that I dont have to go through passport control, just need to go throughs security. I am planning to checkin the stroller and not carry it to the plane to avoid any delay with that; also will have all our liquids in ziplog bag. Any other suggestion to get through security quickly? As per suggestion, downloaded AF app.

I was able to catch the flight. Landed a little early, then was first to get out. They made us board the bus that dropped us to Terminal 2E K. Got into priority 1 line, took 2 min to check the tickets, then next security - took 4-5 min to get through that. Then straight to gate. Once again, appreciate all the help with the answers, due to which I was fully prepared.

Just a few additions to jcaron's excellent answer

CDG has a very confusing layout. There are 3 Terminals (1,2,3), Terminal 2 has different subterminal (2B, 2C, 2E, and 2F) and 2E has multiple concourses (K, L and M).
Gate info for CDG is hard to find but I'm guessing you will stay in 2E for the transfer. Make sure you do NOT leave 2E unless you absolutely sure you have to. Check in online, verify your gate assignments and look on a map.
You WILL have to clear security in CDG. Make sure you go to the business class line. It's not easy to identify.
Memorize a few French terms "classe affaires" and "priorité" As baffling as it: it's not unusual in CDG to deal with dispatchers at security and check in lines who don't speak a single word of English.


Thanks a lot, for your help, will try and memorize some terms. Looking at the previous day's flight looks like both arrival and departure is from 2E; though as you have mentioned I have to be mindful about different subterminal.
